# Get a list of keys that match each item of another given list...?

Tags: python

```
my_dict = {
    'NONE': ['N', 'NE'],
    'VERY SLIGHT': ['VSLT', 'VT'],
    'SLIGHT': ['SLT', 'ST'],
    'FAINT': ['F', 'FT'],
    'MEDIUM': ['M', 'MM'],
    'STRONG': ['S', 'SG'],
    'VERY STRONG': ['VS', 'VG']
}

search_list = ['N', 'SLT', 'MM']

result_list = []
```

I want to search each item of search_list in values of my_dict and return the matching keys as list.

I need... result_list = ['NONE', 'SLIGHT', 'MEDIUM']

I got it by...

```
for i in search_list:
    for k, v in my_dict.items():
        if i in v:
            result_list.append(k)
```

how to get it in more simpler and quickest way to do it?

Comment: I think this is certainly one of the simpler (that is, most straightforward and obvious) ways to do this.

Comment: I'm expecting one liner code...

Comment: "I'm expecting one liner code..." by all means, go for it! But you did say "quickest", it's not the same

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nested comprehension is one option.

```py
[k for k, v in my_dict.items() for x in search_list if x in v]
```

Answer (score 1):

"Flip" your text-to-codes dict to a code-to-text dict (once per your program), and then it's just a simple, fast dict lookup away.

```
text_to_codes = {
    "NONE": ["N", "NE"],
    "VERY SLIGHT": ["VSLT", "VT"],
    "SLIGHT": ["SLT", "ST"],
    "FAINT": ["F", "FT"],
    "MEDIUM": ["M", "MM"],
    "STRONG": ["S", "SG"],
    "VERY STRONG": ["VS", "VG"],
}
code_to_text = {}
for text, codes in text_to_codes.items():
    code_to_text.update({code: text for code in codes})

# `code_to_text` will end up looking like
#   {'N': 'NONE', 'NE': 'NONE', 'VSLT': 'VERY SLIGHT', 'VT': 'VERY SLIGHT', 'SLT': 'SLIGHT', ...
# at this point.

search_list = ["N", "SLT", "MM"]
result_list = [code_to_text[code] for code in search_list]
print(result_list)  # ['NONE', 'SLIGHT', 'MEDIUM']
```

Answer (score 0):

```
search_list = ['N', 'SLT', 'MM']
find_list=[]
for k,v in my_dict.items():
    find_list.extend(map(lambda x: (x,k), v))

dict = {tup[0]: tup[1:] for tup in find_list}

for i in search_list:
    print(dict[i])
```

Answer (score -1):

You could use list comprehension:

```py
search_list = ["N", "SLT", "MM"]
result_list = [k for k, v in my_dict.items() for x in search_list if x in v]
```

This adds the appropriate keys to the result list.
(Add a key only if one of its items is the abbreviation you want.)

On the other hand, you could flip your dictionary, then just look it up:

```py
code_to_text = {}

for k, v in text_to_codes.items():
    code_to_text.update({code: k for code in v})

search_list = ["N", "SLT", "MM"]
result_list = [code_to_text[code] for code in search_list]
```

Both of these give the same value of `result_list`:

```py
['NONE', 'SLIGHT', 'MEDIUM']
```